# Algorithmic approach - Find the best path in a grid

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, dynamic-programming

**Question:** There is an **m** x **n** grid ( **0 <= m, n <= 500**). Each cell in the grid contains  **k** coins (k could be negative or 0 too). You start from **0, 0** and end at **m-1, n-1**, and you can move either 1 step down or 1 step right, collecting as many coins as you can. If **k < 0**, then that particular cell has a robber and you can't move into that cell. If you move into any of the **8** neighboring cells, you will be robbed of **k** coins. How many coins will you have when you reach **m-1, n-1** ?

For example in the grid:

```
0,23,20,-32
13,14,44,-44
23,19,41,9
46,27,20,0
```

ans = 129 (by following the path: 0-13-23-46-27-20-0)

**Time limit: 5 sec**

I don't think this program can be solved using dynamic programming. And I haven't studied graph theory (in case it could be used to solve this problem). The straightforward recursive approach is the only thing I can think of, which is too inefficient under the given constraints.

So what would be a good approach to solve it? Don't just post code, tell me how to begin. If its related to graph theory, then indicating which theorem is involved would be very useful.

Comment: Interesting problem.  Is this a homework problem?  If it is you need to tag it as homework.  The question will still be evaluated by the community.

Comment: It's not a homework problem. I was going through one of codechef's programming contest problems and I came across this. Been at it for 2 days but couldn't come up with a good solution. :-(

Comment: If you have the contents of the grid at the start, it is a graph spanning problem with weighted edges.

Comment: If you move to a square that is adjacent to multiple robbers, do they all take some of your coins?

Comment: Can the number of coins you currently possess become negative, or does it stop at 0?

Comment: The answer could be negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't think this program can be solved using dynamic programming.

Why not? This is a prime candidate for the dynamic programming approach.

> The straightforward recursive approach is the only thing I can think of, which is too inefficient under the given constraints.

Can you build a recursive solution that solves, say, a 5x5 grid? Perfect! Start with that, and then [*memoize*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) it by adding an `MxN` array of best results for cells which you have already solved. Start that array with all large negative values, and then update it when you find a solution that is better. than what's there already. Once you 've finished with the cell, put the solution into the `MxN` array: the next time you come there recursively, check the array for a number, and if a value is there, return it without continuing with the recursion.

The memoized solution itself is rather straightforward. The preprocessing step of the algorithm (subtracting negative numbers from neighboring cells) takes more code.

```
int solve(int r, int c) {
    if(memo[r][c] != MIN) {
        return memo[r][c];
    }
    int res = grid[r][c];
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    if (r+1 != R) {
        a = solve(r+1, c);
    }
    if (c+1 != C) {
        b = solve(r, c+1);
    }
    res = max(res+a, res+b);
    return memo[r][c] = res;
}
```

Here is the solution on [ideone](http://ideone.com/0h9yg), it returns `129` as expected.

Comment: Generally memoization works when there is a grid and multiple queries (so you don't have to calculate the same thing again). Here there's just one query. That's what made me think memoization won't work.

Comment: @Rushil That is incorrect: memoization works pretty much any time when DP works. You do get multiple queries, too: they come from recursive invocations of your own solution.

Comment: @Rushil Specifically, the naive recursive solution does not work fast enough because it solves the same problem over and over again. By calculating a solution once and storing it you get the time complexity to `O(M*N)`.

Comment: Okay well I'll have to think about it. Starting from m-1,n-1 - breaking down the grid into stages and finding out the best decision to make at each cell in every stage, is the solution you're talking about I guess.

Comment: I had thought along the same lines but didn't think it would work! I'll try out this solution and tell you if it got accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is called the [longest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) for a [weighted directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Weighted_directed_acyclic_graphs).

The most number of coins you can have when you reach (x,y) is given by:

```
coins(x,y) = max(coins(x-1,y), coins(x,y-1)) + change
```

This is a [recurrence relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation). It can be solved either by using recursion and memoization for performance, or by using an iterative algorithm.

The iterative algorithm is to work through the grid one diagonal at a time. Start at 0,0. Then calculate 0,1 and 1,0. Then 0,2 and 1,1 and 2,0. etc...

Step 1:

```
 0,  ?,  ?,  ?
 ?,  ?,  ?,  ?
 ?,  ?,  ?,  ?
 ?,  ?,  ?,  ?
```

Step 2:

```
 0, 23,  ?,  ?
13,  ?,  ?,  ?
 ?,  ?,  ?,  ?
 ?,  ?,  ?,  ?
```

Step 3:

```
 0, 23,-33,  ?
13, 37,  ?,  ?   // 37 because of max(23,13) + 14
36,  ?,  ?,  ?
 ?,  ?,  ?,  ?
```

etc...

When you complete this process, the answer is the number in the bottom-right corner.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be described as a [max-flow problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_flow) and thus be solved by the [Ford-Fulkerson-Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm).

Transformation goes as follows:

- Delete the negative nodes and subtract their amount from the neighboring cells.
- 0/0 would be the source, m-1, n-1 the sink
- Each node gets connected to the one below and to the right, the capacity of the arc equals the value of its target node.
- Now the max flow equals the maximum amount of coins you can have

There may be easier solutions, this is just the first thing that came to my mind.

Edit: As dasblinkenlight points out in the comments, this will not work, because a flow is actually the combination of multiple paths, which is of course not what we want here.

Comment: Finding out the max flow is what I was having trouble with. Looks like that algorithm is pretty much what I need. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the flow will work in this case, because Ford-Fulkerson will find the best path for you where you may be collecting coins along multiple valid paths at the same time. For example, the algorithm may send part of the flow to the right and part of the flow down if the rest of the flow network would support it and the resultant flow is maximum, but that is against the constraints in the problem (you can go right or you can go down, but you can't go both right and down at the same time).

Comment: Yes, in that case it won't work. Still I'll check out that algorithm.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: You're right of course... Was pretty tired when I wrote that ;)